# Make type from enum's number values in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

Is it possible to convert enum that looks for exmp:

```
enum StatusCodeEnum {
  OK = 200,
  BAD_REQUEST = 400,
  UNAUTHORIZED = 401,
  FORBIDDEN = 403,
  NOT_FOUND = 404,
  INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 500,
  SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 503,
}
```

to template type that will have only numbers like

```
TypeFromEnum = 200 | 400 | 500 | ...  ---> numbers
```

i only interested in enum transformation without switching to plain Object with "as const"

Comment: It does become a lot easier with the `as const` trick. With `const statusCodes = { OK: 200, … } as const`, `type StatusCode = keyof typeof statusCodes` gives you the enum as a union type and then you can do `type TypeFromEnum = (typeof statusCodes)[StatusCode]`. Any particular reason why you want to avoid this?

Comment: "planeObject" is... what? ✈  Do you mean a "plain object"?

Comment: Enums are intended for use cases when the particular values are not meant to be used directly; if you want `200` you should always and only be using `StatusCodeEnum.OK`.  If you really need a bare `200` then enums are not the right solution for your use case.  Anyway, for the question as asked... right now there's no plausible way to do what you want programmatically, although if [ms/TS#48094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094) is merged there will be.

Comment: I guess you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9EnJN), but it forces the compiler to do a lot of processing to calculate a big union of numbers only to throw away most of them.  So it bogs down performance and is fragile; if you changed any of the `StatusCodeEnum` values to a negative number or a non-integer or a very big number you'd miss things.  It's easier and better to just write the type out manually.

Answer (score 3):

This will be possible in TypeScript 4.8, with [more specific inference from template string types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#infer-types-template-strings).

The approach looks like this:

```
type TypeFromEnum = `${Extract<StatusCodeEnum, number>}` extends 
  `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never;
// type TypeFromEnum = 200 | 400 | 401 | 403 | 404 | 500 | 503
```

You can't easily iterate through a purely [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) because it's not internally represented as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), so the method above first makes sure it grabs only numeric enum members (in case it's a mixed string/numeric enum), converts them to a union of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), and then converts back into numeric literal types via the `infer N extends nmber` technique.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzgYQPYBNgFFzQDeAsAFBRQDyA0lALxQBMADMwDRkUBCAggCIB9AEq4AigFVcMACr0oAFlYdyUcQDke46QAlKQgJIAtXHzmKAjMooAxPV318+uNWeYBmK1DWVpA2+tMGRXlPfTVpXCENABkBGEiANUiBSKE9OQBWJU5YRP00XAF1HgSefWieLmjcTPdlAF8yMjgATwAHYChpduBrACcMCHxIOQADABJCXAAPOD6EAGM4AB54JFRMHGGINigCACNgPoA+etGoYFnQLBQcicIASxAAMyOvC6uQG73IQ76zqAAfneAC49sAAG5HADcZAA9HCoK0Ol0ev1Bts5CxmFAAD4KVh4gnmImKNyk5jyIlZHH4rJuIA)

Answer (score 0):

```
//can use this if you only want specific enum values

type typeFromEnum = StatusCodeEnum.OK | StatusCodeEnum.BAD_REQUEST | StatusCodeEnum.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

// Or this if you want the type to be able to be any of the enum but you might as well just use the enum as the type.
type typeFromEnum = StatusCodeEnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
type StatusCodeType = `${StatusCodeEnum}`

// return -> `200 | 400 | 401 | ... `
```

Comment: This results in `"200" | "400" | ...`, which are *strings*, not *numbers*.